# How to assign a post to a post parrent?

Tags: posts, query-posts

I want to be able to add posts to a post parent in wordpress. Is there a way? 
There is such option for pages but I need it for posts to. Any ideeas?

Ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posts & Pages are "built in" Custom Post Types. So something that was delivered as a pre-configuration when WP was installed. There's also other built in stuff like Tags & Categories which are basically nothing other than custom taxonomies.

And you're lucky: You can simply use the API and [add your own](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), hierarchical custom "post" type.

```
register_post_type( 'hierarchical' => true );
```

Comment: Very interesting, ty. That's it, I just need to paste this line inside my functions .php?

Comment: No, you need to follow the link and assign those values that don't have defaults. Then you need to add this to your functions.php file. And then you have to query for your new post type instead for the default built in post types. This means modifying the template files of your theme.

Answer (score 0):

Posts are designed to be chronological. Pages hierarchical. If you are trying to make posts hierarchical, you are using WordPress all wrong. Custom post-types are your solution but it's not a walk in the park...